# Is it possible to use koudoku for one-time payments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, stripe-payments

This post references: https://github.com/andrewculver/koudoku

I'd like to use Koudoku for one time payments as opposed to recurring billing. I do not see any way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Koudoku is specifically designed for recurring subscriptions.

If you're just looking to do one-off payments, I recommend just following the [standard Stripe tutorial for a payments page](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms).

To support returning customers or additional purchases, I recommend simply using Devise for authentication and then saving whatever the resulting Stripe customer ID is from the first purchase in the user model, so you can run additional charges against the same card in the future.

Comment: what if I need recurring subscriptions AND individual purchases or packages, does Koudoku support that?